# How to Make a JSON from two string arrays - 1st array having values & 2nd array having ids in same sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
Array 1 = Accessories:Bracket,Accessories:Clamp,Actuator:Accessories,Actuator:Accessories:Bracket,Actuator:Accessories:Clamp,Actuator:Clevis

Array 2 = 24092859,24092784,24094450,24094451,24110219,24092811
```

Required Output =

```
[
  {
    "text": "Accessories",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Bracket",
        "children": [],
        "mtdtId": "24092859"
      },
      {
        "text": "Clamp",
        "children": [],
        "mtdtId": "24092784"
      }
    ],
    "mtdtId": "24092859,24092784"
  },
  {
    "text": "Actuator",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Accessories",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "Bracket",
            "children": [],
            "mtdtId": "24094451"
          },
          {
            "text": "Clamp",
            "children": [],
            "mtdtId": "24110219"
          }
        ],
        "mtdtId": "24110219,24094451"
      },
      {
        "text": "Clevis",
        "children": [],
        "mtdtId": ""
      }
    ],
    "mtdtId": "24110219,24094451"
  }
]
```

the parent should contain the id's of the child nodes.

Comment: nice, what have you tried?

Comment: Is there a reason Clevis doesn't have an `mtdId` of `"24092811"`?

Comment: i am able to get id for the child elements. but the task to get all of the id's of the children in there parents is where i am stuck

Comment: @searlea , no , that is just left by mistake

Comment: The parent should have all the mtdtIds available in child nodes

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array1 = "Accessories:Bracket,Accessories:Clamp,Actuator:Accessories,Actuator:Accessories:Bracket,Actuator:Accessories:Clamp,Actuator:Clevis".split(
  ","
);
const array2 = "24092859,24092784,24094450,24094451,24110219,24092811".split(
  ","
);

const output = array1.reduce(
  (topLevelNodes, path, i) => {
    let nodes = topLevelNodes;
    let mtdId = array2[i];
    path.split(":").forEach(text => {
      let node = nodes.filter(child => child.text === text)[0];
      if (node) {
        node.mtdId += "," + mtdId;
      } else {
        nodes.push((node = { text, children: [], mtdId }));
      }
      nodes = node.children;
    });
    return topLevelNodes;
  },
  []
);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks.. while using this coed, i am getting some JS Syntax errors like _Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Arguments_ Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) etc

Comment: The answer uses new JavaScript syntax.  There's a brilliant tool called babel you can use to convert to older syntax.  Cut'n'paste the answer into the left-hand-side of this page: https://babeljs.io/repl/ - and you'll see equivalent JavaScript using older syntax appear in the right-hand-side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the nested elements and get later all values of `mtdtId` for grouping of the children elements. I suggest to use a different property for the collection.

```js
var array1 = 'Engines:Combustion,Engines:Combustion:AeroThermal,Engines:Combustion:Fuel Systems,Engines:Combustion:Mechanical,Engines:Fans & Compressors,Engines:Fans & Compressors:Centrifugal Compressor Aero'.split(','),
    array2 = '001,002,003,004,005,006'.split(','),
    result = [];

array1.forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.split(':').reduce(function (r, k, j, kk) {
        if (!r[k]) {
            r[k] = { _: [] };
            r._.push(j + 1 === kk.length ? { text: k, mtdtId: array2[i], children: r[k]._ } : { text: k, children: r[k]._ });
        }
        return r[k];
    }, this);
}, { _: result });

result.reduce(function iter(r, a) {
    var temp = a.mtdtId ? [a.mtdtId] : [];
    if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
        temp = a.children.reduce(iter, temp);
    }
    if (a.mtdtId !== temp.join()) {
        a.collected = temp.join();
    }
    return r.concat(temp);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for such a good solution.Only issue i am getting is if a node is selected and also its children are selected, in that case two separate node are getting created one with children and without

Comment: Engines:Combustion,Engines:Combustion:AeroThermal,Engines:Combustion:Fuel Systems,Engines:Combustion:Mechanical,Engines:Fans & Compressors,Engines:Fans & Compressors:Centrifugal Compressor Aero

Comment: in the above comment you can see that the Combustion is also Selected and inside Combustion Aerothermal & Fuel systems are selected .. So combustion must have its id and its children id ... @ninaScholz

Comment: {
  "text": "Combustion",
        "children": [],
        "mtdtId": "24137217"
      },
      {
        "text": "Combustion",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "AeroThermal",
            "children": [],
            "mtdtId": "24137220"
          },
          {
            "text": "Fuel Systems",
            "children": [],
            "mtdtId": "24137218"
          },
          {
            "text": "Mechanical",
            "children": [],
            "mtdtId": "24137219"
          }
        ],
        "mtdtId": "24137220,24137218,24137219"
      }